# Subclassed QWidget not visible

Tags: python, pyqt, subclass, pyside, qwidget

I have the most simple form of a subclassed `QWidget`:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent=parent,*args,**kwargs)

        print(self.parent().objectName())


def e(e,v,t):
    sys.__excepthook__(e,v,t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.excepthook = e
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = QWidget(objectName="MainWindow")
    mainWindow.setLayout(QHBoxLayout(mainWindow))

    widget1 = Widget(mainWindow,styleSheet="background-color: red")
    widget2 = QWidget(mainWindow,styleSheet="background-color: green")

    mainWindow.layout().addWidget(widget1)
    mainWindow.layout().addWidget(widget2)

    mainWindow.showMaximized()

    app.exec_()
```

When I run the program, only the `QWidget` shows, and there is a gap for where the `Widget` should be:
[image: Current window]

If I change the `Widget` to a `QWidget`, then the correct image is shown in the window:
[image]

I have tried:

- `widget1.show()`.
- `widget1.raise_()`.
- `widget1.setVisible(True)`.
- `widget1.parent().setVisible(True)`.
- All of the above inside and outside the `Widget` constructor.
- Tried `PySide2`, `PySide6`, `PyQt5`, `PyQt6` (`app.exec_()` needs to be `app.exec()` for `PyQt6`).

Also:

- `print(self.styleSheet()` in the `Widget` constructor prints `background-color: red` showing the `**kwargs are being correctly set`.
- In the constructor of `Widget`, `"MainWindow"` is printed, showing that the parent has been set correctly as `"MainWindow"` is the objectName of the top level window I have created (`mainWindow`).
- Tried using PyCharm and built in Python IDLE.

System

- Python 3.9
- PyQt6.0.1/PySide6.0.1
- Windows 10

I can not for the life of me see why the `Widget` class will not show; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_StyledBackground, True)` in `__init__` and add `from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt`

Comment: spoiler: The widget is shown but the problem is that the stylesheet is not used by default in a custom widget so you have to activate some flags

Comment: @eyllanesc Is it the only flag that needs to be activated in custom QWidget or should I go through all attributes and set the default values manually?